# Дано целое число n(вводится с клавиатуры). Вычислить сумму из n слагаемых

Tags: c, ряды

Задание: Дано целое число n(вводится с клавиатуры). Вычислить сумму из n слагаемых:
[image]

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
int n, y = 1, m = 0;
printf("Введите n: "); scanf("%d", &n);
while (n !=0)  { // Факториал
        y = y * n ;
        n = n - 1;
}
while (n!=0) { // Знаменатель
    m = m + ((n + n + 1) * (n + n + 1));
    n = n - 1;
}
printf("%d", y);
printf("\n%d", m);
}
```

Пока что делаю просто набросок, столкнулся с проблемой, что в m у меня выводит m=0 и оно не меняется. В чем может быть ошибка? Делаю ведь сложение m + какое-то число.

Comment: Так после первого цикла `n` будет нулем. Как потом может выполниться второй цикл?

Comment: Точно. А как тогда это делать? Через For, а нe while?

Comment: Сохраните введенное значение n в другой переменной и потом используйте его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто аккуратно записать все шаги ([ideone](https://ideone.com/8WCV0T)).
При вычислении sum можно использовать формулу, ну да ладно.

```
int n, last = 0, f = 1;
printf("Введите n: "); scanf("%d", &n);
double res = 0;
for(int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
   f *= i;
   int sum = 0;   
   for(int k=last+1; k <= last+i; k++) 
       sum += k; 
    last += i;
    res += 1.0 * f / (sum * sum);
}
printf("%f", res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int n;
scanf("%u",&n);
double term = 1.0, sum = 1.0;
for(unsigned int k = 2; k <= n; ++k)
{
    double a = k - 3. + (3.*k+1.)/(k*k+1.);
    sum += term *= a*a/k;
}
printf("%.10lf\n",sum);
```

Полный код [здесь](https://ideone.com/kYb1VI).

Answer (score 1):

Вы в цикле `while` уменьшаете `n` до нуля из-за этого второй цикл `while` просто не выполняется.

Решить это можно создав  дополнительную переменную, а в циклах использовать другую, хотя правельней будет вынести вычисление факториала в отдельную функцию